# Reorder form controls using Mozilla React form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsonschema

I am trying to play around with [react-jsonschema form](https://mozilla-services.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/) of Mozilla.

I have my jsonschema as

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "street_address": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "city": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "state": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "street_address",
        "city",
        "state"
      ]
    },
    "node": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "children": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/node"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "billing_address": {
      "title": "Billing address",
      "$ref": "#/definitions/address"
    },
    "shipping_address": {
      "title": "Shipping address",
      "$ref": "#/definitions/address"
    },
    "tree": {
      "title": "Recursive references",
      "$ref": "#/definitions/node"
    }
  }
}
```

UiSchema as

```
{
  "ui:order": [
    "shipping_address",
    "billing_address",
    "tree"
  ]
}
```

Using reorder I can control the order of controls on the ui, but as shipping address has street address,city and state. How can I control the ui:order of these controls, consider I want city to appear first within shipping address, how can I do that using Mozilla React jsonschema form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add order at the shipping address level.

```
{
  "shipping_address": {
    "ui:order": [
      "city",
      "*"
    ]
  },
  "ui:order": [
    "shipping_address",
    "billing_address",
    "tree"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try @ver01/form [here](https://ver01.com/form/playground/index.html)

with schema this:

```
{
"definitions": {
    "address": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "street_address": {
                "title": "street_address",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "city": {
                "title": "city",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "state": {
                "title": "state",
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "street_address",
            "city",
            "state"
        ]
    },
    "node": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "title": "name",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "children": {
                "title": "children",
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/node"
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "billing_address": {
        "title": "Billing address",
        "$ref": "#/definitions/address"
    },
    "shipping_address": {
        "title": "Shipping address",
        "$ref": "#/definitions/address",
        "$vf_opt": {
            "option": {
                "order": [
                    "city",
                    "*"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "tree": {
        "title": "Recursive references",
        "$ref": "#/definitions/node"
    }
},
"$vf_opt": {
    "option": {
        "order": [
            "shipping_address",
            "billing_address",
            "tree"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of what you fixed and where in the code you fixed the problem.

Comment: Just give another form solution with this order require